# How can I get the results of this mathematical expression?

Tags: c, math

I have this math calculation in my app and I can't understand how to calculate it.

```
(-5992*12*(1-1/(1+5.25%/12)^(25*12))/5.25%)=
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%.0lf",pow(-5992*12*(1-1/(1+(5.25/100))/12), ((-5992*12))/(5.25/100)));
```

Can someone please help me figure it out?

Comment: Break it into pieces and see what happens?

Comment: @sarnold  But you have to be careful because if they fall on the floor those pieces can be hard to find.

Comment: @Peter: and sharp, too. :) But sometimes things just need to be broken into their component pieces to understand them...

Comment: i just did it: i will post my answer in 8 hours :) THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to get? What you've literally got amounts to:

```
-66,210.9 ^ -1,369,599
= 1 / (-66,210.9 ^ 1,369,599)
= 1 / (an exceedingly large number)
~= 0
```

Is it possible you've put something in the exponent that you don't want there?

Comment: That's what I was about to post...